# Generating regular point grid on 3d planar surfaces

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

I want to generate points that lies on 3d surfaces. In my case these surfaces are builidng walls and roofs in a 3d city model. How can I generate these points ? What are the algorithms for this purpose? I want to generate points on surfaces as in the attaching picture [picture of points on surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut9Fn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your surfaces could be subdivided by rectangles and triangles (rectangles often are considered as two triangles).

Every piece has base vertex `A0 (x0, y0, z0)` and two neighbor vertices `A1` and `A2`. Make base vectors

```
 V1 = A1 - A0
 V2 = A2 - A0
```

To make regular grid points inside this piece of plane, just calculate

```
P(u, v) = A0 + V1 * u + V2 * v
```

where u and v are equally-spaced parameters in range 0..1. Additional limitation for triangles

```
u+v <= 1
```